# Account ticker symbol - how to update it in Apex

Tags: apex

Remote server sends me ticker symbol as "NYSE:LLY".  How do I update this information into TickerSymbol field in Account. It is a standard field in Account object with field type Content(20)

I didn't find any online help..

Comment: what invokes the remote server call?  more info is needed here to get help -- question is too broad

Answer (score 1):

With what limited information you've given us, take a look at the [Salesforce Docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_account.htm) for TickerSymbol.

Although the field type is Content, it has the following properties:

> - Type: String
> - Properties: Create, Filter, Group, Nillable, Sort, Update
> - Description: The stock market symbol for this account. Maximum of 20 characters.

This means all you have to do is get the value from your remote server, however you do that, and put the value into the TickerSymbol field as a String, and Salesforce should handle it as a Content type.

Content is just a unique data type in that any String you enter here will be processed as a Ticker Symbol. Clicking on it will send you to another website (I believe Yahoo!) showing the current stock price.